# How to Fill underneath area below line graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I using PNLine chart Graph ( https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart ) everything is working fine, I just want to know how to fill underneath area below line graph.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Underneath area means which one can you clarify more about it?

Comment: the area below the line..how to fill that using PNline chart

Comment: below lines means? are you talking about X-Axis?

Comment: I want to fill the area under the drawn graph (i.e. the area under the graph line) ex:https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjovS.png